# Current flow in non-inverting op-amp amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

How does the current flow in this particular circuit? I know that \$R_3\$ isn't important as there is no current flow (ideal op-amp). I want to calculate the different currents with Kirchhoff's junction rule, but I'm really stuck right now, because I don't know the flow directions of the currents.

[image]

(\$U_\mathrm{e}\$ and \$U_\mathrm{a}\$ are the same as \$V_\mathrm{e}\$ and \$V_\mathrm{a}\$).

Comment: You don't need to know the current directions as they depend on the voltage. You must know what is the relation of voltage at non-inverting and inverting inputs of an ideal op-amp and you have your answer.

Comment: What is your primary goal? To find the various currents or to calculate the resulting gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of points that make things much easier:

1. Current doesn't flow into or out of the op-amps *inputs*, because they have infinite impedance. It's as if the op-amp isn't even there.
2. With negative feedback, the op-amp produces whatever output is necessary to equalise the potential at its two inputs. Therefore, \$V_{inverting} = V_{non-inverting} = V_e\$

From point 2, it's clear that the voltage across \$R_3\$ is zero, and no current flows through it. You can remove \$R_3\$, and the system would still settle into the same equilibrium.

The op-amp is effectively a voltage source of value \$V_a\$, and we can redraw the circuit without \$R_3\$, and with the condition \$V_{inverting} = V_e\$, as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffQcqm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since *you* provide the value of input \$V_e\$, that's a known quantity. The only unknown is \$V_a\$, which is some value that the op-amp provides to obtain the condition \$V_{inverting} = V_{non-inverting} = V_e\$. With only one unknown, this system has a solution - it's your task to find a value for \$V_a\$ that will obtain potential \$V_e\$ at the point shown.

In doing so, not only do you find the currents and potentials everywhere, but you also find the gain \$\frac{V_a}{V_e}\$, as a bonus gift.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's an ideal op-amp so no current flows into the op-amp terminals and V+ = V- = Ve. So, current flowing through R3 is 0.

Current through R4 is Ve/R4.

Apply voltage divider to get node voltage between R1 and R5, call it Vx. Current through R5 is Vx/R5 and through R2 is (Ve-Vx)/R2.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the current flow in this particular circuit?

What is an ideal op-amp?

See this first. [LF13741](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/L/F/1/3/LF13741N.shtml) is a FET input op-amp.
Note that R3 current is very low and should be zero.

[image]

And here is same circuit with "ideal" opamp (gain=1e6), but no offset, etc  ...

[image]